# RavenDb Linq query greater and lower comparison

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb, nosql

I have simple index in RavenDB:

Maps:

```
from q in docs.Questions
from Tag in q.Tags
select new { Tag, Count = 1 }
```

Reduce

```
from result in results
group result by result.Tag into g
select new { Tag = g.Key, Count = g.Sum(x=>x.Count) }
```

And i have some code to invoke it:

```
var query = from item in session.Query<TagCount>("Questions/Tags") select item;
Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
foreach (var result in query)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", result.Tag, result.Count);
}
```

It produce output:

```
3
Games - 1
RavenDb - 2
Intro - 1
```

as expected.
But, if add some code after this loop:

```
var counted = from item in query
 where item.Count > 0
 select item;
Console.WriteLine(counted.Count());
```

Output would be:

```
3
Games - 1
RavenDb - 2
Intro - 1
0
```

WTF? Why counted count is zero?

But if i have '==' in counted comparison, it works:

```
var counted = from item in query
 where item.Count == 1
 select item;
Console.WriteLine(counted.Count());
```

Produces

```
3
Games - 1
RavenDb - 2
Intro - 1
2
```

Whats going on?

Comment: what do you get if you do this: `var results = session.Query<TagCount>("Questions/Tags").ToList(); var count = results.Count;` ??

Comment: count is 3; And if i change counted query to select from 'result', not from 'query' it works like expected. But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a problem was that i have not add Field to index to store and analyse it.
Adding Field to query and set analyzing on this field solves problem.